# How to write data to an existing json file in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to add data to an existing json file in assets folder in flutter based on input given by user?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model as your JSON and add the fromJson toJson method. Call the model class and pass your new data init.
Read this documation: **https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Assets are read-only.
Read this for options on how to persist data between app runs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence